# How to delete all occurrences (0 or many) of a character between two strings in SAS

Tags: regex, sas

I am trying to parse a .json file into SAS. In order to deal with lists in the .json file, I would like to remove all commas from between [item1, item2, item3, .... itemn], but keep the commas that are not within [].

I think I should be able to do this using prxchange regular expression...I can get it working for a two item list, but can't figure out how to alter it to work with lists of different amounts.

`newvariable=prxchange('s/(\[\w+),(\w+\])/$1 $2',-1,oldvariable);`

Examples:

```
oldvariable = "{"hospital": "NOP", "drugs": ["penicillin", "ampicillin", "cephalosporin"]}" 
newvariable = "{"hospital": "NOP", "drugs": ["penicillin" "ampicillin" "cephalosporin"]}" 

oldvariable = "{"hospital": "KOP", "drugs": ["tetracycline"]}" 
newvariable = "{"hospital": "KOP", "drugs": ["tetracycline"]}"
```

Maybe there is a better way to approach this...

Comment: If you haven't read it already, Murphy Choy's paper is pretty useful here: http://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings13/296-2013.pdf  He's also a regular poster on the SAS-L mailing list, if you run into anything you can't figure out here.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes the easiest way to handle a regex is to break it into steps. In this case, first get the array out, then replace the commas with spaces:

```
data _null_;
oldvariable = '{"hospital": "NOP", "drugs": ["penicillin", "ampicillin", "cephalosporin"]}';
arrayExpr=prxparse( '/\[[^]]+\]/' );
call prxsubstr( arrayExpr, oldvariable, position, length );
put position length;
newvariable=cat(
    substr( oldvariable, 1, position - 1 ),
    prxchange( 's/, / /', -1, substr( oldvariable, position, length ) ),
    substr( oldvariable, position + length )
);
put newvariable;
run;
```

Your original regex had some problems as well. Of the many regex-helper sites [this one is my favorite](http://www.regextester.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of SAS's DSD option (which allows you to use quotation marks to ignore embedded delimiters) if you do a smaller prxchange, similar to Leo's suggestion.

```
data have;
infile datalines dlm=',' dsd;
input @;
_prx = prxparse('s~\[([0-9,]*?)\]~"$1"~io');
_prxm = prxmatch(_prx,_infile_);
if _prxm then call prxchange(_prx,-1,_infile_);
_test_=_infile_;
input a b $ c d $;
datalines;
1,Hello,2,3
2,Goodbye,3,[4,5,6]
;;;;
run;
```

In your case I'm not sure if double quotation marks would work, since they have a meaning in JSON, but you could use single quotes just as well.